# Azure databricks: KafkaUtils createDirectStream causes Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty") error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, azure-databricks

In Azure databricks, I tried to create a kafka stream in notebook and used it to create a spark 
 job. Databricks throw error at the line KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(). Attached the correponding code below.

```
from kazoo.client import KazooClient
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils, TopicAndPartition

sc = spark.sparkContext
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)
print('SSC created:: {}'.format(ssc))
zk = KazooClient(hosts=kafka_host)
print(kafka_host)
zk.start()
_offset_directory = "/" + topic + "/" + "DA_DAINT" + "/partitions"
print(_offset_directory)

if zk.exists(_offset_directory):
    partitions = zk.get_children(_offset_directory)
    print(partitions)
    partition_offsets_dict = {}
    for partition in partitions:
        offset, stat = zk.get((_offset_directory + '/' + partition))
        partition_offsets_dict[partition] = offset.decode()
    print(partition_offsets_dict)
    from_offset = {}
    for _partition in partitions:
        offset = partition_offsets_dict[_partition]
        topic_partition = TopicAndPartition(topic, int(_partition))
        from_offset[topic_partition] = int(offset)
    print(from_offset)
    print("\nCreate kafka direct stream ...")

    kafka_stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": broker_list},
                                                 fromOffsets=from_offset)
```

Attaching the error stack traces.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1159, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty
```

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
```

```
An error occurred while calling 
o581.createTopicAndPartition Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<command-3832551107104577>", line 77, in <module> fromOffsets=from_offset) 
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 141, in createDirectStream v) for (k, v) in fromOffsets.items()]) 
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 141, in <listcomp> v) for (k, v) in fromOffsets.items()]) 
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", 
line 314, in _jTopicAndPartition return helper.createTopicAndPartition(self._topic, self._partition) 
File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", 
line 1257, in __call__ answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name) 
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", 
line 63, in deco return f(*a, **kw) 
File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 336, in get_return_value format(target_id, ".", name)) 
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o581.createTopicAndPartition
```

In Azure databricks, when using Kafka stream in python notebook, I have installed **kafka-python** and **org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.1** libraries and added them as a dependencies to the spark-job in databricks.

**Note 1:**
Also i am able to receive data from Kafka when i use simple kafka consumer in databricks notebook.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
if __name__ == "__main__":
    consumer_ = KafkaConsumer(group_id='test', bootstrap_servers=['my_kafka_server:9092'])
    print(consumer_.topics())
    consumer_.subscribe(topics=['dev_test'])
    for m in consumer_:
        print(m)
```

The problem arises only, if i try to create Kafka direct stream using *KafkaUtils.createDirectStream()* in azure databricks python notebook.

Another minimal set of code for reproducing this issue,

```
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

broker = "broker:9092"
topic = "dev_topic"

sc = spark.sparkContext
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)
dks = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": broker})
print("Direct stream created...")
parsed = dks.map(lambda v: v[1])
summary_dstream = parsed.count().map(lambda x: 'Words in this batch: %s' % x)
print(summary_dstream)
```

**NOTE 2:** 
Kafka version: 0.10
Scala version: 2.11
Spark version: 2.4.3

Comment: I have created a corresponding issue in databricks forum.
https://forums.databricks.com/questions/28433/kafkautilscreatedirectstream-causes-py4jnetworkerr.html

Comment: Try the following simple snippet, before you pass data into kazoo: 
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils 
broker = "broker:9092" 
topic = "topic_name" 
dks = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": broker}) parsed = dks.map(lambda v: v[1]) 
summary_dstream = parsed.count().map(lambda x:'Words in this batch: %s' % x) summary_dstream.pprint()

If this doesn't work, try a different jar. You seem to use `0.8_2`, but errors refer to `0.10_7` so you might have a mismatch there. I am aware there are two (0.8 and 0.10) live jars.

Comment: `0.8_2` is the kafka stream version used. I think it should be in sync with the java version. I tried with 0.10 jar. But it still searches for 0.8 jar.
`Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one of the following.
1. Include the Kafka library and its dependencies with in the
spark-submit command as
$ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8:2.4.3.
Then, 
$ bin/spark-submit --jars <spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly.jar>`

Comment: Ah, in which case the problem then might be the submit args in your Databricks notebook. Try to make sure that the `spark-submit` in your notebook is running with the following (or similar) args: `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.3`
This would explain why your data can be accessed directly by a Kafka consumer, but not by Spark, as there might be mismatch in the submit args.

Comment: `org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.1` dependency should match the version of Spark used in the notebook (see that `2.0.1` part that is for the Spark version). Make also sure that `_2.11` matches the version of Scala in use in the notebook. The last recommendation is to use [Structured Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) instead. That's the modern Spark Streaming that is no longer supported.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I tried with spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11-2.4.3.jar which matches the scala version of notebook (2.11) and spark version (2.4.3) and the issue still remains

Comment: kafka-python works, so what do you need from Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still i am unable to get the root cause of the issue.
But using the jar org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:2.4.3 fixed the issue.

**UPDATE 1:**
Got the following update from microsoft support team:

> Below is the update from databricks engineering.
>
> We see the customer
>   is using DStreams API
>   (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/rdd-streaming/)
>   which is outdated and we don't support it anymore. Also, we strongly recommend them switch
>   to Structured Streaming, you can follow this doc for doing it -
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/structured-streaming/kafka

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Could you accept the answer?